# rspec testing a class method giving object not spied or stubbed error

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec3

Rspec testing

I have class called Client.

```
class Client
  class << self
    def shutdown
      puts 'shutting down the producer gracefully'

      @producer ||= k_producer.producer(opts)
      @producer.shutdown
    end

    private
    def k_producer
      Kafka.new([127.0.0.1:9092], { required_acks: :all })
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test the shutdown class method and i do not understand the concept of stubbing or spy.

Im trying this way

```
RSpec.describe Client do
  describe "Client.shutdown" do
    it "calls shutdown" do
      described_class.shutdown
      expect(described_class).to have_received(:shutdown)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error where i do not know how to tell the rspec that i have @producer inside my class and shutdown is called on it.

```
Client (class)> expected to have received shutdown, but that object is not a spy or method has not been stubbed
```

Comment: Do you want to test that `Client.shutdown` is called, or `@producer.shutdown`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never set up `described_class` as a spy. You'd do this by making it a [partial double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/basics/spies#spy-on-a-method-on-a-partial-double) with [`allow`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/basics/allowing-messages).

```
RSpec.describe Client do
  describe "Client.shutdown" do
    it "calls shutdown" do
      allow(described_class).to receive(:shutdown)
      described_class.shutdown
      expect(described_class).to have_received(:shutdown)
    end
  end
end
```

However, this test is tautological. You're simply testing that the test called `Client.shutdown`. It's more useful to test that `@producer.shutdown` is called.

It's a bit troublesome to get at @producer. We can make Client easier to test, and more flexible in general, by adding accessors for its internal objects.

```
class Client
  class << self
    # Define only the writers: producer= and kafka=
    attr_writer :producer, :kafka

    # Define the readers ourselves with our defaults.
    def producer
      @producer ||= kafka.producer(opts)
    end

    def kafka
      @kafka ||= Kafka.new(["127.0.0.1:9092"], { required_acks: :all })
    end

    def shutdown
      puts 'shutting down the producer gracefully'

      producer.shutdown
    end
  end
end
```

Now we make a spy and set it as the producer.

```
RSpec.describe Client do
  describe "Client.shutdown" do
    it "calls @producer.shutdown" do
      producer = spy("producer")
      described_class.producer = producer
      
      described_class.shutdown

      expect(producer).to have_received(:shutdown)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: could u please recommend me some rspec ebooks from where i can start this testing from sratch.

Comment: in fact i want to try the both.

Comment: @Ajith I've added how to test `@producer.producer`. I can't recommend an e-book, sorry. I find [Thoughtbot's articles](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tags/rspec) to be very useful as well as [betterspecs.org](http://www.betterspecs.org/). And I highly recommend [rubocop-rspec](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rspec/) (and regular rubocop) to audit your code and learn from its recommendations.